# AWS SNS - Platform application is disabled

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

We use Amazon SNS to send push notifications to our users. We recently renewed the certificates but for some reason we nog get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
   <Error>
      <Type>Sender</Type>
      <Code>PlatformApplicationDisabled</Code>
      <Message>Platform application is disabled</Message>
   </Error>
</ErrorResponse>
```

We haven't changed anything to the code or to the certificates. 
When I verify the certificates using `openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert myapnsappcert.pem -key myapnsappprivatekey.pem` everything also works fine. The only problem is that the notifications for iOS won't be sent due to the error. Android is working fine.

Comment: Hi Bart! I've just run into same issue. Have you succeeded in resolving it?

Comment: This is because the user deleted the app  (or disabled notifications). Apple can't send notifications to this user so it will communicate this with AWS. AWS then disables that user. This message is for single users, not for all of them.

Comment: @BartBergmans: I got the same error but its resulting in disabling of platform application and need to enable again and again. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

The error can caused because your p.12 is expired, you can create a new one or update the current in AWS SNS.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Zoe, thanks for your comment, i'm new at the stack overflow community :)